# How can I implement firestore into my ionic react project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

In my ionic react project I have tried to implement firebase's firestore using the official google docs. However, I get an error in my IDE under `const db = firebase.firestore();`

This is the error I get where PROJECT_FOLDER is the director to my project.

> Property 'firestore' does not exist on type 'typeof import("PROJECT_FOLDER/node_modules/firebase/app/dist/app/index")'.ts(2339)

It seems strange that my IDE recognises some of the installed package functions like `firebase.initializeApp()` but not `firebase.firestore()`. My versions of firebase and firestore under package.json are 10.8.0 and 4.4.2 respectively. Any feedback would be useful as I am relatively new to typescript.

**Current Implementation**

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";

// TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
// See: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY',
  authDomain: 'YOUR_AUTH_DOMAIN',
  projectId: 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID',
  storageBucket: 'YOUR_STORAGE_BUCKET',
  messagingSenderId: 'YOUR_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID',
  appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID',
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Initialize Cloud Firestore and get a reference to the service
const db = firebase.firestore();

db.collection("users").add({
    first: "Ada",
    last: "Lovelace",
    born: 1815
})
.then((docRef) => {
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
});
```

Comment: This is not how imports of Firebase work since version 9 and up. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade

Comment: I've tried using the other method as well on the docs (Web modular API) where it uses `import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";` and `import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";` - both implementations create a faulty Firestore object for me.

Comment: First off: does the link I provided explain why the code you have in your question doesn't work with the version of the Firebase SDK you're trying to use? --- If you can't get the SDK to load with the modular syntax in the link either, edit your question to show a [minimal repro](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue with my implementation. I used the web modular API format for importing and setting up firebase and firestore, and I used the web namespace API format for adding to the database. Not sure why using the incorrect importation method isn't picked up by VS Code but whatever.

**What my code should have been**

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore, collection, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

// TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
// See: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY',
  authDomain: 'YOUR_AUTH_DOMAIN',
  projectId: 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID',
  storageBucket: 'YOUR_STORAGE_BUCKET',
  messagingSenderId: 'YOUR_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID',
  appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID',
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Initialize Cloud Firestore and get a reference to the service
const db = getFirestore(app);

try {
  const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
    first: "Ada",
    last: "Lovelace",
    born: 1815
  });
  console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
} catch (e) {
  console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
}
```